# MS Word VBA - open file with parameters, string longer than 255 chracters

Tags: vba, macros, ms-word

I'm developing a MS Word macro which needs to open a file on a network drive and pass it the calling file's path as a parameter (i can then retrieve the parameters in the opened file using this method http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-21174.html).

What i am trying to achieve is the following:

```
1. Document X (any MS word document) calls document Y (macro document)
2. Document Y processes document X (using the Document object)
3. Document Y closes
```

The reason i am doing step 1 above is do that users don't have to deploy complex vba code (i am dealing with non IT literate users) and the ease of making updates and enhancements to the code if required.

The following code snippet opens the file with parameters:

```
Dim currentFilePath As String
currentFilePath = ThisDocument.Path & ThisDocument.Name

Dim MacroFilePath As String
MacroFilePath = ThisDocument.Path & "\Test.docm"
MacroFilePath = """" & MacroFilePath & """" & currentFilePath
Documents.Open (MacroFilePath)
```

The value of 'MacroFilePath' is gets setup like this (263 chars):

```
“\\XXXXXXXXXXXX\XX_XX\XXX_XXX XXXX procedural documentation\XX Design Support\Macros - DO NOT MOVE\Work in progress\Calling Document.docm” \\XXXXXXXXXXXX\XX_XX\XXX_XXX XXXX procedural documentation\XX Design Support\Macros - DO NOT MOVE\Work in progress\Test.docm
```

When I run the above code the error *Run-Time '9105': String is longer than 255 characters* occurs. I have tested the code where i moved the files to a shorter directory and it works. Is there a way to get around this or another way of achieving what i am trying to do?

**Shorting the file paths by saving the documents elsewhere, changing the language i am programming in, or creating any kind of executable is not an option as i am in an enterprise environment.**

Comment: @Dirk Vollmar The issue there is that the calling document would be locked by the user. While i can design a macro that would allow the user to browse for a file and process that way; this method is preferable.

Comment: X can't open Y, then call a procedure in Y and pass in it's own path as a parameter ?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838935.aspx

Comment: @Tim Williams Not sure what you mean, X is opening Y with X's path a s a parameter, Y's OnLoad even is running and retrieving the parameter... As for can X directly call a procedure in Y? as far as i know this is impossible in VBA.

Comment: You can use Application.Run from X to call a procedure in Y and pass it a parameter...   Check the link I posted.

Comment: @Tim Williams Thanks, that worked! i did not realize VBA had that capability. If you add an answer below i will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X can open Y, then call a procedure in Y and pass in it's own path as a parameter.

You can use `Application.Run` to do this.

See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838935.aspx

Here's the example from that link:

```
Dim strTemplate As String 
Dim strModule As String 
Dim strMacro As String 
Dim strParameter As String 

strTemplate = InputBox("Enter the template name") 
strModule = InputBox("Enter the module name") 
strMacro = InputBox("Enter the macro name") 
strParameter = InputBox("Enter a parameter value") 
Application.Run MacroName:=strTemplate & "." _ 
                & strModule & "." & strMacro, _ 
                varg1:=strParameter
```

Comment: Please explain how you tested this solution. Using "Application.Run" produced the same path length error message when I tested it using a path > 256 characters. And the MS documentation on maximum path appears to suggest it should not work see: [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx) (scroll down).

Comment: @Roberto The original reason I was getting the maximum file path error was due to the fact I was concatenating 2 file paths (file to open + current file address), when I passed this to Documents.Open it crashed with error 9150.

Now I use Documents.Open to just open the file (document Y from my question), then use Application.Run to call the method required in document Y with the file path of document X as a parameter.